# Dimensions of a sphere and a ball

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, lebesgue-measure

The volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is denoted by $v_{n}$ and the surface area of the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is denoted by $\omega_{n-1}$.

What is the importance of writing $n-1$ and $n$?

Comment: The $k$ in $\mathbb{S}^k$,resp $B_1^k$, refers to the dimension of the sphere, resp Ball , when seen as a manifold. For some purposes (see Differential Topology, for instance) it is convenient to have $k$ match the dimension of the sphere, and not the ambient space (which has dimension $k+1$) in which it is usually embedded.

Comment: @b00nheT Could you give me a reference which explain this fact more explictly.

Comment: I wouldn't know what reference to give you, as I do not know your background. But maybe the simplest explanation is that $B_1^k$ has dimension $k$ (as it is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$), and thus its boundary, which is nothing but $\mathbb{S}^{k-1}$, has dimension $1$ less, hence $k-1$. Is this sufficient?
In very loose terms, in low dimensions: the boundary of a $3D$ object, such as a Ball, is a $2D$ surface, and the boundary of a $2D$ object, such as a circle, is a $1D$ curve.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to denote the $n$ in your $n$-ball because there are $n$ different unit balls in $\mathbb{R}_n$ and you have to indicate which you are referring to.

E.g. a low-dimensional ball is a segment between a pair of points - the points being a low-dimensional sphere.  If you add one more dimension then your ball is a disk, which is the contents of a circle, then add another dimension and you have the ball you naturally know, which is the contents of a sphere and exists in any set of dimensions $\geq 3$.

The same principle applies to spheres.

Comment: I couldn't undertsand what does it mean "there are $n-1$ different unit balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$."

Comment: If n is 4 then you are in the space $\mathbb{R}^4$, then there are 3 different types of unit ball: $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$.

Comment: Sorry, 4 different types.  $v_1$ is a line segment, $v_2$ is a disc, $v_3$ is the ball you know and $v_4$ is a hypersphere of greater dimension than you can imagine.

Comment: @user315531 a n-sphere is a set of points equidistant from some point. On a line, a 1-sphere is a pair of points.  On a plane, a 1-sphere is still a pair of points and a 2-sphere is a circle. In a 3-d space, 1-sphere and 2-sphere are still the same plus you have 3-sphere which is the sphere you normally think of when I say "sphere". And so on...